# Why is the maximum message size of the SHA-1 hash function (2^64) - 1 bits?

Tags: security, hash, cryptography, sha1, sha

The title of the question describes everything.

As described on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Comparison_of_SHA_functions 
Why is the maximum message size for the SHA-1 hash function limited to (2^64) - 1 bits?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography and as such it's more suitable for http://crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: how to move to that forum ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in hash finalization the unsigned 64-bit message length is appended to the last block and hashed.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But why is only unsigned 64-bit message length ? why is it not larger.

Comment: Because it is how algorithm designed, and that length would be enough for any message length in a nearest future.

Comment: 1) It will take a long time until we reach messages longer than 2^64 bits which we want to hash sequentially. For large files hash-trees which allow parallel computation and don't suffer from this limitation are preferable. 2) SHA-1 has a security level of 2^80 bits to *generic* collision attacks. Attackers reach that level of power long before single files reach 2^64 bits. So this issue is more interesting for SHA-256 than for SHA-1.

Comment: It is not prepended, it is appended as the last 64-bit to from the block.